Crypt setup boot problem
I have the following error after formatting a Lenovo Thinkpad T14 computer with Ubuntu version 24.04.1:
cryptsetup warning option 'cipher' missing in crypttab for plain dm crypt mapping dm_crypt-0
My steps are as follows:

Boot with iso 24.04.1
Disk encryption by ZFS
Default partitioning selection
No joining to AD

Once started, I decrypted the disk, then connect graphically to the session, perform an apt update and apt uprgade, then reboot.
There the message appears on every boot while decrypting the disk. Thank you.
